# Method that gets index and returns an object in a specified index

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a method that gets index and returns a object in a specified index. For example if I have.

```
List<Shape> _shapes;

public Shape GetShape(int index)
{
          return _shapes.Method()
}
```

I want to get the shape in the index sent.

Comment: What's collection do you use? Always list? Or you want generic method for different collections?

Comment: i think its fine thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List <Shape> _shapes;

public Shape GetShape(int index)
{
  return _shape[index]
}
```

It is absolutely possible and valid to access an specific index of an enumeration using this syntax in C#.